# How can I make a submit button issue a post of the form but have the result coming back placed into an element HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a single page web application. I added the following code for login:

```
$('#loginLink, #registerLink')
   .click(function () {
      var $link = $(this);
      var href = $link.attr('data-href');
      $('#article').load(href);
   }
   return false;
});
```

This works and populates the #article section with the following HTML. Note that I 
stripped out some of the code for this question:

```
<form action="/User/Account/Login" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
...
note there's client side validation on the page but I just don't show it here
...
<ol>
   <li>
      <input id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="">
   </li>
</ol>
<input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

When the form appears if I click on the submit then it sends a request to 
the browser and this returns with a new page. Is there a way I can still 
keep the submit action (for client side validation which is on my page) 
but have the result of the submit bring back a page that again displays 
in the #article section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can still keep the submit action (for client side
>   validation which is on my page) but have the result of the submit
>   bring back a page that again displays in the #article section?

Not sure I understand this correctly but if you want to load article content without a page re-fresh on submit you could bind to the `submit` event and execute an ajax call similar to this:

> *I'm using `on` in the example below which was only added in jQuery 1.7. If you are using jQuery 1.6.x or lower you can use `bind` instead.*

```
$("form").on("submit", function() {
    var $form = $(this);

    // if there are validation errors do not continue.
    if(!$form.valid()){
        return false;
    }

    // get the form data
    var myData = $form.serialize();

    // get the url to post to from the form's action attribute.
    var myUrl = $form.attr("action");

    // execute the post
    $.ajax({
        url: myUrl,
        data: myData 
        success: function(data) {
            // on success, write the returned article content into the article element
            $('#article').html(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});​
```

Comment: Will this still perform a submit to trigger jQuery client validation?

Comment: @SamanthaJ: `$form.valid()` executes the validation as it would with the current submit and returns false if the form has validation errors. In that case you don't continue with the submit. I also just fixed the logical issue with my if statement as well `if($form.valid()){` should have been `if(!$form.valid()){`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `event.preventDefault()` to avoid sending form and reloading the entire webpage. See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3BgK/1/).